# How save fast changing barometeric data

Tags: sensor, sense-hat

I have problems with vibrations from my neighbours (I am very sure about the source). I have found out that the vibrations as they go through the airways in the ventilation system, the best way to track them is to record the changes in air pressure.
I have a mock setup with the pi sense hat - but I will probably use the bmp286 sensor. However, the principle should be pretty much the same.

I find when I do `python barometer.py > somedata.txt` and then after aprox 5 sseconds `ctrl^c`
and then `wc -l somedata.txt`gives 599 lines of data. then `sort -u | somedata.txt` gives 134 lines. So i guess it would be possible to compress the data at a quite fair level. It is needed to keep the duplicate reading as they show how often things changes. Also It is needed to get some kind of 'timestamp' to the readings. 
The question is - is there any standard procedure to store this kind of data and also compress it.?  It does not be 'court-grade, just good enough to show some experts in the field so they understand that I need their help. And why I not take contact with the experts in the first instance - well I have my reasons, and that is out of the scope for this question.

With my very limited knoweledge I guess that I couldcstore the data in a wav-file.?
As the  data is recorded on a rpi, there is also a need to transfer the  data.

Comment: How large will the file be if you don't compress the data?  I'm confident that if you want to use this data as "proof" the experts will need to see the original unprocessed data.

Comment: timestamp is easy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14320620/9111962 (just add it to the output of barometer.py and redirect it to somedata.txt)

Comment: Do you use python 2 or 3?

Comment: python 2: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html | python 3:https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html